# Set joint rotation range?

Tags: gazebo-2.2

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone, I was wondering if there is a way to specify minimum and maximum angles of rotation for a joint? I want part of my robot to be partially articulated but the specific function shouldn't rotate the full 360 degrees.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7601/set-joint-rotation-range?/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-12-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

On your model's SDF file, you can specify the [joint's upper and lower limits](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/sdformat/api/dev.html#limit385) in radians.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2014-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-12-01**:
Just the answer I was looking for, thanks. I still haven't gotten used to the new SDF API yet.